# Enforcing the priority of libraries in Android gradle build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, operator-precedence

I work on a framework which is delivered to the customer as a set of `.aar` files, which are then included into their project, like this:

```
...
+-- assets
+-- libs
      +-- framework-module1.aar
      +-- framework-module2.aar
      +-- framework-module3.aar
      +-- customer.aar
+-- main
...
```

The framework consists of a number of modules which are generic for all customers, and one `customer.aar` which provides the customer-specific code and configuration. The idea is that code/resources in `customer.aar` override the default code/resources per customer's needs.

**The problem is:** when the final `.apk` is built, sometimes the values are custom (as intended) but sometimes they are still the default ones. I guess, the order of `.aars` being assembled is not correct those times.

*There are mentions of library priority in the documentation of the build tools, but they are only relevant to the old Eclipse-based build system and not to Gradle-based one.*

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
...
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs file('libs')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'framework-module1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'framework-module2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'framework-module3', ext:'aar')

    compile(name:'customer', ext:'aar')
}
...
```

Is there a way I can tell Gradle that `customer.aar` must always come last in the build?

Comment: For my experience you can't specify the order of dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Resources are processed by Android build tools  in the order opposite to that declared in Gradle script. The code responsible for the order is [found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools.build/builder/0.14.0/com/android/builder/core/VariantConfiguration.java#VariantConfiguration.getResourceSets%28java.util.List%2Cboolean%29), if you're queries.

Swapping just one line around has solved the problem:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'customer', ext:'aar')

    compile(name:'framework-module1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'framework-module2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'framework-module3', ext:'aar')
}
```

Remember to `clean` your build after altering the order of dependencies! Gradle does **not** detect it automatically.

*Note that this "reversed" order applies only when resources are coming from android libraries, i.e. when the dependency is `aar` file. In the case when dependency is another project or module, the normal (non-reversed) order is in force.*